# Twitter Bootstrap 2.1 affix-plugin doesn't work properly

Tags: css, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap

As title...I'm using Bootstrap 2.1 with affix as sidebar. But when I scroll down, another column suddenly move to left under my sidebar like this:

Scroll before: [image]

After Scroll: [image]

Here is my code:

```
    <section class="container">
      <article>
        <div class="row">
          <aside class="sidebar span3" data-offset-top="150" data-spy="affix">
            <ul class="nav nav-list">
              <li><a href="#toc_0">標題1<i class="icon-chevron-right pull-right"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#toc_1">標題2<i class="icon-chevron-right pull-right"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#toc_2">標題3<i class="icon-chevron-right pull-right"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#toc_3">標題4<i class="icon-chevron-right pull-right"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#toc_4">標題5<i class="icon-chevron-right pull-right"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
          </aside>
          <div class="span9">
```

Comment: Do you have any additional CSS to share that might be relevant?

Comment: I tried to remove all css I made but only bootstrap. But problem is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the element is 'affixed', the CSS for the element becomes `position: fixed`, which is why you get the poor floating issue.  On the Bootstrap documentation pages, the Affix plugin is always attached to the `<ul>` element, not the `.sidebar`.

Try

```
<aside class="sidebar span3">
  <ul class="nav nav-list" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="150">
    ...
  </ul>
</aside>
```

### [JSFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/mmfansler/t4Wex/)

Comment: I did this like you but still doesn't work and I don't know why.